# Boolean question in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, boolean

I am making a game in Cocos2d. I have enemies in the game. I want them to shoot at the character. Currently, I have a boolean that says

```
buffDude.shoot = YES
```

when it is done moving. And in the Enemy class, I want it to detect if the boolean is YES or NO, and shoot if it is YES. And, while we're on that note, if I declare

```
buffDude.shoot = YES
```

in the

```
+(id)enemy
```

method, it will create a bullet at the bottom of the enemy sprite, but the bullet will not move. I know that it is because it didn't add the bullet to the Layer, it added it to the Enemy, but I don't know how to add it to the layer. Please Help! This is really driving me crazy, and help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Okay, to get it to work, I just created a different layer and added the enemies and their bullets to that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, do you want to know how to make the bullet move, or how to add it to a layer?

Comment: @Fraser Graham okay, so i have a boolean that is declared YES in the HelloWorldLayer.m. When it is declared yes, i want the Enemies class to detect it, and perform a method based on the boolean. It creates the bullet on the Enemies sprite, not on the HelloWorldLayer layer, do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do. But I can only assume that you are adding a bullet sprite. And if you are adding a bullet sprite in you Enemy Class like: `[self addChild:bulletSprite];`, the Enemy class will own that bullet. Instead, if you would like the bullet to be visible in your game scene, you can add the same code in HelloWorldLayer.m instead.

But as I said, I'm not really sure what your problem is.

Comment: i want to be able to say enemy.shot = YES in HelloWorldLayer.m and have Enemies.m do something based on what the Boolean is.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 I'm still not sure exactly what you want to do and why. Have you thought about rethinking the problem? Can you post some relevant code from both classes?

Comment: i edited the question to tell exactly what i did to fix it. BTW i fixed it.